# My visa expired in Malaysia 3 years ago

Tags: visas, overstaying, malaysia

my visa was expired in Malaysia 3 years ago. Will I be blacklisted if I go back to my country?

Do I need to prepare any materials? what information do I need to prepare so as not to be blacklisted? lt's very important for me!!!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you still in Malaysia? If so, what type of visa did you have? What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 2):

The Malaysian Immigration Department takes the offence of overstaying a visa very seriously. A foreigner who stays in Malaysia exceeding the expiry date or cancellation of their visa is liable to pay a fine or be imprisoned for up to five years or a combination. https://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/main-services/syarat-kemasukan-ke-malaysia-en/frequently-committed-offences/

You should go to the Malaysian Immigration Enforcement Division to explain your situation to them and present relevant documents, for example:

- Valid passport
- Police report (in the case of a lost/missing passport)
- Evidence of the length of your overstay eg your original visa, entry stamp
- Means to buy a plane, bus, or ferry ticket to leave the country within 7 days.
- If you are an employee of a Malaysian company, documentation from your Malaysian employer.

The Malaysian Immigration Department has the final say on whether to allow you to leave (if your reason for overstaying is deemed acceptable) or to prosecute you for overstaying and any other Immigration offences such as working illegally. Should they choose the latter option, you must seek legal representation.

In any event, AFAIK you can expect to be blacklisted for up to 5 years, or even permanently banned.

Comment: This answer is technically correct but naive: the OP risks being sent to immigration detention if not jail, both of which are famously unpleasant, if they do this.  There are no good options at this point, but it would still be preferable to go the airport with a flight ticket and RM10,000 in hand (they might let them leave if lucky) or to explore, uhh, *unofficial* crossings to Thailand (which is  hugely illegal, but only if caught).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wouldn't OP have problems in Thailand as well since he'd have to enter illegally unless he's willing to pass through a malaysian border control - which is exactly what he should probably avoid?

Comment: @lambshaanxy it's just as illegal if you don't get caught, but in that case there is no punishment.

Comment: @ThiefMaster You'd want to bypass Malaysian control but arrive legally in Thailand, typically by sailing on a boat.

Comment: @lambshaanxy The OP asked about avoiding being blacklisted, would leaving via an *unofficial* route help, or is it a given?

Comment: @Traveller At this point getting blacklisted is the least of their worries, even if they go the legal route they will not be welcome back for many years.

Comment: can the embassy of the OP's origin country help them leave the country without being jailed?

Comment: @njzk2 I imagine the embassy could offer the OP advice, make sure they are treated properly, perhaps help contact family for financial assistance etc but it’s not going to interfere in local immigration / judicial processes as such

Comment: Hmm I guess the boat-to-thailand approach could work: He's out of MY, enters into TH legally, and then requests a proper visa for MY. Dunno how computerized they are, but they might either not realize that on paper the OP is still in MY at all, or assume someone at the border control forgot to record the departure. Depending on passport stamps it may be wise to get a new passport though, in order to not have a MY entry stamp but no exit stamp...

Anyway, all very illegal or at least shady, leaving MY and never going back would probably be the safer choice for OP...